# Can't find Python.h file on CentOS

Tags: python, c, centos

I am trying to compile a Python extension written in C on a CentOS machine. I am getting

```
error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

It works fine on ubuntu, where I have python-dev installed using apt-get.

I tried installing python-devel using

```
yum install python-devel
```

but it is already installed. How do I fix this error?

Comment: open up a terminal and type `find / -name Python.h 2>/dev/null`  does anything come up?

Comment: also What version of CentOS are you on?

Comment: I had the same problem on `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503` and `yum install python-devel` fixed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On my system the `Python.h` header file is in the path `/usr/include/python2.6/`. As this path is not searched by the pre-processor by default, you have to add it to the list of paths to search. This is done with the `-I` option to the compiler, like this:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/include/python2.6 source.c -o program
```

Change the path above to the actual path on your system. You can find it either with the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command as proposed in a comment, of with the [`locate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) command if it's installed.

Comment: ah, sorry, I see, it's the c source file, sorry

Comment: -1. Generally I do not recommend hardcoding any external flags for compilaton. See pkg-config tool that helps resolving some compile-time flags, like: `pkg-config python --cflags` .

Answer (score 43):

If you using python3 You could install python34-devel for that

It's available on [EPEL Repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and has [python34-devel package](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/python34-devel.html) available

You simply just run this command to get it installed

```
yum install python34-devel
```

Hope it's help

***note** At this time `python34-devel` is the most updated version of python 3.4

Comment: `2.7 => python-devel`
`3.4 => python34-devel`
`3.6 => python36-devel`

Answer (score 14):

- for `CentOS 7.4`

  - `Python 3.6.6` : `yum -y install python36-devel`
  - `Python 2` : `yum -y install python-devel`
- for `Ubuntu`

  - `Python 3.6`: `apt-get install libpython3.6-dev`

Comment: `yum -y install python3-devel` will install the latest available python3 version for that version of CentOS.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue and build my docker image  by `yum -y install python3-devel`. Previously I installed `python3-dev` and I was able to build my image. Is there a name change recently?

Answer (score 2):

For centos 8+

```
dnf install -y python3-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are running Centos 8 , you can use :

```
dnf install -y python38-devel
```

dnf install -y *python3-devel* did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install `python3.4` (include pip) & `python3.4-dev` packages on Centos6.X:

```
yum install http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/python34u-3.4.2-1.ius.centos6.x86_64.rpm
yum install http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/python34u-devel-3.4.2-1.ius.centos6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where default Python was 2.7 but pip was running against 3.4, and I wanted to use 2.7. So I did: `yum remove python34-pip` and `yum install python2-pip`. Solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar problem.

> ./python/py_defines.h:39:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or
>   directory

Whereas the find command showed that the `python.h` exists.

The above solutions did not work however the below command execution worked for me.

```
yum install python27-python-devel.x86_64
```

Not much different but wasted lots of time.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the Python you have!

You need a `dev` package, the version X.X.X for Python X.X.X you have, you can search on https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-x86_64.

By example, if you have Python 3.6.5 from IUS, you need to install https://centos.pkgs.org/7/ius-x86_64/python36u-devel-3.6.5-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Python3.9 on Centos8. I fixed it by installing as below:

```
dnf install -y python39-devel
```

Comment: answer is a replica of another one