# Include <Python.h> to makefile.am

Tags: python, c++, c, python-2.7, makefile

I apologize for this newbie question. I am currently looking to embedded a small python code into a main C code. It has been suggested to use `#include <Python.h>` at the header. I have already done so and that my Ubuntu12-0.4 machine also has `python-dev` installed.

By running `locate Python.h`, I got `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h`.

However, when I include Python.h into my C program, it still gives me `fatal error: python.h: No such file or directory`.

So Python.h hasn't been include in the Makefile. But I have no idea how to do so.  Looking into my package list I have: `Makefile.am`,`Makefile.in`, and `Makefile`.

---

In Makefile.am:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
EXTRA_DIST = MIGRATION README.rst libmodbus.spec
SUBDIRS = src doc tests

pkgconfigdir = $(libdir)/pkgconfig
pkgconfig_DATA = libmodbus.pc
```

In Makefile.in,
the first line  says

`# Makefile.in generated by automake 1.14.1 from Makefile.am.`

Should I also include the complete description of `Makefile.in` to here? I am not sure how should I proceed.

Comment: I don't know about `automake`, but when you invoke `g++`, I think there should be an option `-L/usr/include/python2.7`.  (`/usr/include` is appended to the search list automatically, but I don't think this is recursive.)

Comment: @JamesKanze `-I /usr/include/python2.7` Uppercase `i` -- not `L` -- that's for libraries. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux You're right.  It should be `-I`.  You may need a `-R` as well, or something to tell the linker and the executable where to look for the library as well (unless  it is in `/usr/lib`).  I don't have a Unix system handy to check, but you might also verify the capitalization; your error message says `python.h`, not `Python.h`.

Comment: So, do I just add that to my Makefile.am?

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong `Makefile.am`. Most likely you want the one in `src` if that is where your program is being compiled. You can try setting `AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/python2.7` in that file and regenerate the Makefiles. That's probably only appropriate for an experimental patch, though - the "right" way to do it is generally to modify `configure.ac` to have autoconf locate Python and set up the proper flags.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error, try this:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 yoursource.c -o yourprogram
```

This solution is from:
[Can't find Python.h file on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379929/cant-find-python-h-file-on-centos)